# Showing two generalized inequalities for convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

## Question 1

Let $f:(0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function, and $x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n > 0$. Show that
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + \dots + x_n) f \left( \dfrac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{y_1 + \dots + y_n}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i f \left( \dfrac{y_i}{x_i}\right)
\end{align*}

### Attempted answer

Is it an application of [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for $\phi (x_i) = \frac{x_i}{y_i}$?

## Question 2

Prove that $f(x) = (1+x^p)^{1/p}$ is convex in $(0, + \infty)$ when $p \geq 1$ and then conclude that
\begin{align}
((x_1 + \dots + x_n)^{p} + (y_1 + \dots + y_n)^{p})^{1/p} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}^{p} + y_{i}^{p})^{1/p}.
\end{align}

### Attempted answer

Calculating the second derivative yields
\begin{align}
f''(x) = \left(p-1\right)x^{p-2}\cdot\left(x^p+1\right)^{\frac{1}{p}-2} \geq 0, \ \forall p \geq 1
\end{align}
however I do not understand how that is tied to the result that is expected.

Comment: Are you sure about the first inequality ? I think it should be $(x_1 + \dots + x_n) f \left( \dfrac{y_1 + \dots + y_n}{x_1 + \dots + x_n}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i f \left( \dfrac{y_i}{x_i}\right)$

Comment: It's exactly like that, maybe you saw something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, it follows using the Jensen inequality as you mentioned.
Given that the sequences $ \{x_i\}_i $ and $\{y_i\}_i$ are strictly positive real numbers
\begin{align} 
(\sum_i x_i)f\left(\frac{\sum_i \color{red}{{y}_i}}{\sum_i \color{red}{{x}_i}}\right) = (\sum_i x_i)f\left(\frac{\sum_i x_i \frac{y_i}{x_i}}{\sum_i x_i}\right) \leq^{\text{Jensen}} (\sum_i x_i)\frac{\sum_i x_i f\left(\frac{y_i}{x_i}\right)}{\sum_i x_i} = \sum_i x_i f\left(\frac{y_i}{x_i}\right)
\end{align}

For question 2, it is just an application of question 1. Given that $f$ is a convex function, we have

\begin{align}
((\sum_ix_i)^{p} + (\sum_ix_i)^{p})^{1/p} &= \sum_ix_i \left(1 + \left( \frac{\sum_iy_i}{\sum_ix_i}\right)^p\right)^{1/p} = \sum_ix_i f\left(\frac{\sum_i y_i}{\sum_i x_i}\right) \\
&\leq^{Q2} \sum_i x_i f\left(\frac{y_i}{x_i}\right) = \sum_i (x_{i}^{p} + y_{i}^{p})^{1/p}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will attempt to verify it once I get off work and I will get back to you. Have a good one!